# Overriding a module subroutine from a class subroutine

Tags: perl

I have a class which has an ability to define a credentials.

```perl
$po = PoService->new()->set_basicauth("jack", "secret");
```

The thing is, in order to do that, it has to redefine a module subroutine. So, I did it this way:

```perl
sub set_basicauth {
  my ($self, $creds_username, $creds_password) = @_;

  sub SOAP::Transport::HTTP::Client::get_basic_credentials {
    return $creds_username => $creds_password;
  }

  return $self;
}
```

But, when I run the code, it tells me a message:

```
Variable "$creds_username" will not stay shared at /opt/PoService.pm line 53.
Variable "$creds_password" will not stay shared at /opt/PoService.pm line 53.
```

What did I do wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the mix of a lexical (`my`) variable and a nested subroutine.

The inner subroutine closes over the two variables it uses.  However, being lexical they get redefined on each new call, while the inner (*named*) sub faithfully keeps reference to the original values.  So the whole thing may work as expected only the first time it's called.

Luckily, we get the warning to that fact.  With `use diagnostics;` added (or see [perldiag](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldiag.html))

> Variable "$x" will not stay shared at -e line 1 (#1)
> (W closure) An inner (nested) named subroutine is referencing a
> lexical variable defined in an outer named subroutine.

> When the inner subroutine is called, it will see the value of
> the outer subroutine's variable as it was before and during the *first*
> call to the outer subroutine; in this case, after the first call to the
> outer subroutine is complete, the inner and outer subroutines will no
> longer share a common value for the variable.  In other words, the
> variable will no longer be shared.

> This problem can usually be solved by making the inner subroutine
> anonymous, using the sub {} syntax.  When inner anonymous subs that
> reference variables in outer subroutines are created, they
> are automatically rebound to the current values of such variables.

While this explains the matter the solution won't work for your purpose, if I understand it right.

One approach that seems suitable is to fully qualify names

```
sub SOAP::Transport::HTTP::Client::get_basic_credentials {
  return $main::$creds_username => $main::$creds_password;
}

sub set_basicauth {
  my $self = shift;

  ($main::$creds_username, $main::$creds_password) = @_;

  # ... (not sure of your purpose, presumably use SOAP::)

  return $self;
}
```

where `$main` should be substituted for the actual package name, if different. The sub *can* be placed inside the other but there is no purpose to that since it is compiled as any other named sub.

Another option would be to make variables global with [our](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/our.html).

Comment: Thanks @zdim. I've fixed the solution into a working one.

Comment: @sancho21  Great :).  Thank you for the suggested edit. However, declaring `my` vars is something else. It introduces a lexical, which is effectively global in this case (in the larger scope anyway). If you then refer to it (`$var`) it's _that_ lexical, not the `$main::var` -- which you _always_ have to call `$main::var`.  The `$main::var` creates an entry in the symbol table (while `my $var` doesn't). They don't need to be declared when fully qualified (if it didn't work there must've been another reason).  I'll add some comments, or links (but later, it's too late now here).

Answer (score 2):

There's no such thing as a nested named subs.

```
sub set_basicauth {
  my ($self, $username, $password) = @_;

  $self->{username} = $username;
  $self->{password} = $password;
}

sub request {    
  my ($self, ...) = @_;

  my $username = $self->{username};
  my $password = $self->{password};

  local *SOAP::Transport::HTTP::Client::get_basic_credentials = sub {
    return $username => $password;
  };

  ... code that uses SOAP::Lite ...
}
```