# Perl Function Scoping with my

Tags: perl, scope

I am confused with the behavior difference between the following two code segments:

```
$x = 8;
sub a {
    sub b {
        print "B: $x\n";
    }
    my $x = 3;
    &b();
}
&a();
```

and

```
$x = 8;
sub a {
    my $x = 3;
    sub b {
        print "B: $x\n";
    }
    &b();
}
&a();
```

While the first one outputs B:8, the second one outputs B:3. Shouldn't they output the same value, as the outer scope of sub b should be sub a? How does the different placements of functions make a difference?

Comment: `use warnings; use diagnostics;`

Comment: It matters where `my` variable is defined, as it's visible in sub/block/etc. only after definition (no hoisting like `var` in javascript)

Comment: See also [Nested subroutines and Scoping in Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10192228/2173773)

Comment: Related [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45670363/4653379) on nesting subroutines

Comment: I'm not sure where you're learning Perl from - but using `&` on subroutine calls is a bit of a clue that you're using a really old tutorial. That hasn't been necessary for over twenty years.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Others have already pointed out the issue with nested `sub`s, but here is my answer to my understanding of your question:

The "scope" of a `my` declaration begins after the statement that contains the `my`, not at the beginning of the block it occurs in. Otherwise, both of these would work:

```
$ perl -wMstrict -le 'sub foo { my $bar="quz"; print $bar; } foo()'
quz
$ perl -wMstrict -le 'sub foo { print $bar; my $bar="quz"; } foo()'
Global symbol "$bar" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my $bar"?) at -e line 1.
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.
```

Also, note the following:

```
my $x = 3;
{
    my $x = $x + 5;
    print "1: $x\n";  # prints "1: 8"
}
print "2: $x\n";      # prints "2: 3"
```

In your first piece of code, at the point you declare `sub b`, Perl only knows about the global `$x = 8`, so that's what `print "B: $x\n"` is using. In the second piece of code, Perl has seen `my $x = 3`, so that's what it uses. This effect also occurs if you don't use nested `sub`s:

```
my $x = 8;
sub a {
    my $subb = sub {
        print "B: $x\n";
    };
    my $x = 3;
    $subb->();
}
a();  # prints "B: 8"
```

and

```
my $x = 8;
sub a {
    my $x = 3;
    my $subb = sub {
        print "B: $x\n";
    };
    $subb->();
}
a();  # prints "B: 3"
```

Answer (score 3):

This problem arises from having nested named subs.

There's no reason to have nested name subs in Perl since the inner sub is in no way scoped to the outer sub.

Instead, use:

```
sub p {
    my ($x) = @_;

    local *q = sub {
        say $x;
    };

    q();
}

p($_) for 3, 4;
```

or

```
sub p {
    my ($x) = @_;

    my $q = sub {
        say $x;
    };

    $q->();
}

p($_) for 3, 4;
```